Access to an article of Freydoon Shahidi
I am learning Rankin-Selberg integral and I want to refer to a work of shahidi, On multiplicativity of local factors. In Festschrift in honor of I. I. Piatetski-Shapiro on the occasion of his sixtieth birthday, Part II (Ramat Aviv, 1989), volume 3 of Israel Math. Conf. Proc., pages 279-289. Weizmann, Jerusalem, 1990.
([56] in https://www.math.purdue.edu/people/profile/fshahidi.html)
But it turns out that there is only part I ( vol 2 of Israel Math. Conf. Proc ) on libgen and I can't find this document on scihub.
To be honest, this is the first time that I can't find some document on scihub or libgen.

Not sure about scihub/libgen, but for another free alternative, you might be able to find it in a university library, see here

@TobErnack unfortunately, my university isn't a member of this system, so i don't have access to this document
